# stop kernel audit messages logged in syslog without disabling auditing

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, audit, auditd, journald

OS: CentOS 7

I am trying to figure out how audit (`kaudit`) events are logged in `/var/log/messages`.

I have enabled `audit=1` in grub which means when the server boots, kernel auditing is enabled. This is the desired state for the particular system and disabling audit is out of the equation. My `audit` configuration is as follows

```
  #  auditctl -s
enabled 1
failure 1
pid 0
rate_limit 0
backlog_limit 64
lost 7452643
backlog 0
loginuid_immutable 0 unlocked
```

`Auditd` on the other side is disabled/stopped because I am using another tool to collect/consume those events generated by kernel audit.

My problem is that I noticed those audit events are logged in `/var/log/messages`:

```
2021-11-25T00:35:09.490607-08:00 myserver.local kernel: [4272426.343673] audit: type=1110 audit(1637829309.455:7426414): pid=2361 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success
```

I am trying to figure out how these messages end up in `/var/log/messages` and the only thing I am sure is that syslog will do this.

Actually, I am trying to trace how the audit events end up in `rsyslog` and so far I had no luck. I have an assumption that `journald` is fetching those audit events which in turn forwards them to `rsyslog` however, I am not able to clarify this.

`Journald` can establish a `netlink socket` with the kernel to get audit events, however I don't see such socket present in systemd.

```
 #  systemctl list-units --type=socket
UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
dbus.socket                  loaded active running   D-Bus System Message Bus Socket
dm-event.socket              loaded active listening Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs
iscsid.socket                loaded active running   Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket
iscsiuio.socket              loaded active listening Open-iSCSI iscsiuio Socket
lvm2-lvmetad.socket          loaded active listening LVM2 metadata daemon socket
lvm2-lvmpolld.socket         loaded active listening LVM2 poll daemon socket
nscd.socket                  loaded active running   Name Service Cache Daemon Socket
rpcbind.socket               loaded active running   RPCbind Server Activation Socket
systemd-initctl.socket       loaded active listening /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe
systemd-journald.socket      loaded active running   Journal Socket
systemd-shutdownd.socket     loaded active listening Delayed Shutdown Socket
systemd-udevd-control.socket loaded active running   udev Control Socket
systemd-udevd-kernel.socket  loaded active running   udev Kernel Socket


#  systemctl status systemd-journald-audit.socket
Unit systemd-journald-audit.socket could not be found.
```

Now weird thing is that if I list `netlink` sockets in the system, I can see one related to `audit` and `systemd` :

```
#   ss -a -f netlink|grep audit
UNCONN 0      0              audit:systemd/1                        *
UNCONN 0      0              audit:sudo/3144                        *
UNCONN 0      0              audit:kernel                           *
UNCONN 0      0              audit:sudo/14889                       *
```

Any idea how these logs end up to syslog and what/how this `audit:systemd` socket is created?

Most importantly , how to stop `journald` gathering audit events?